# Web Chat doesn't work, but Telegram / Facebook / Emulator etc. work fine

Tags: botframework

I have a chatbot created with the MS bot framework. It works great in Telegram, on the portal, facebook messenger, and the emulator - but the Web Chat doesn't work.

It will connect and let me type things in, but none of the responses get back to the web chat window. I even see the message coming in and being sent back from my chatbot in the server logs, but somehow it doesn't make its way back to the web chat.

**Any idea why?**

The bot is called WffBot, and the web chat link is [here](https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/wffbot?s=1tQsxMhZDAE.cwA.duQ.lwco44W695fVtFzhzg7zwxEsKyj2UnYGDWEyR00uihY).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had the address and name in the from section of the JSON of the response switched. While, for whatever reason, none of the other messaging systems minded this, the WebChat just ignores the responses.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this? I have the same issue? Was it finally resolved and web chat worked at the end?